# Загрузка изображения при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html

я в javascript новичек . Подскажите как сделать загрузку изображении при нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: Стилизуй input под кнопку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для загрузки и отображения картинок можно использовать элемент `<img>`. В обработчике события щелчка по кнопке мы создаём новый элемент [HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) с помощью метода [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/document.createElement). Затем указываем адрес картинки в атрибуте src. Как только новый объект будет готов, его нужно обязательно добавить к текущей странице с помощью вызова [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

```js
document.getElementById('t').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var l = document.createElement('img');
  l.src = 'https://placehold.it/150x200';
  document.body.appendChild(l);
});
```

```css
button { display: block }
img { margin: 5px }
```

```html
<button id="t">click me</button>
```